# Извлечь параметры querystring на java script

Tags: javascript, asp

Есть некий код на яваскрипте (со вставками классического ASP), который заполняет экселевскую табличку данными из БД.
В заголовке таблички нужно написать значение из querystring. Пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом, но все время получаю ошибку

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
    Sheet.Cells(1,1)="Анализ звонков ( "+<%=Request.QueryString("region")%>+")";
</script>
```

Параметр region в строке запроса присутствует.
Остальной код, заполняющий таблицу, работает без ошибок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте взять `<%=Request.QueryString("region")%>` в кавычки либо вписать прямо в строку: "Анализ звонков (`<%=Request.QueryString("region")%>`)".

Comment: Второй вариант заработал, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал написать так:

Sheet.Cells(1,1)="Анализ звонков (`<%=**" +** Request.QueryString("region") **+ "**%>`)";